# Livewire3: all css and js re-render on every livewire component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

On seeing the network tab, all js are called for every livewire component changes, I have all js calls, <livewire:sidebar /> and {{ $slot }} in master.blade.php, calling every link in sidebar loads the component and all js files, am I doing something wrong? Attached it the image for only the app.js file call.[App.js re-render for every livewire component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWRIF.png)

The js files only needed to load once at first component load.

> admin\layouts\master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    @include('admin.layouts.header-scripts')
    <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">
    
        @include('admin.layouts.nav')
    
        <livewire:sidebar />
    
        {{ $slot }}
    
    </div>
    @include('admin.layouts.footer-scripts')
    </body>
    </html>
```

> admin\layouts\header-scripts

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
        <title> {{ $title ?? 'Home' }} | Admin Panel </title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://www.w3schools.com/favicon.ico">
        <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('bower_components/admin-lte/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}}">
        <!-- Theme style -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('bower_components/admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('bower_components/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('bower_components/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('bower_components/admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('bower_components/admin-lte/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.css')}}">
    
        <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
        @yield('styles')
        @livewireStyles
    </head>
```

> admin\layouts\footer-scripts

```
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <script src="{{ asset('bower_components/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="{{ asset('bower_components/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.min.js') }}"></script>
    
    @yield('js')
    @livewireScripts
```

> views\livewire\sidebar.blade

```
    <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
        
        <div class="sidebar">
            
            <nav class="mt-2">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu"
                    data-accordion="false">
                    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/home" wire:navigate
                           class="nav-link {{ request()->is('home') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-home"></i>
                            Dashboard
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/getAbout" wire:navigate
                           class="nav-link {{ request()->is('getAbout*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-cog"></i>
                            About Us
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            
        </div>
    </aside>
```

> web.php

```
    Route::get('/home', HomeIndex::class);

    Route::get('/getAbout', AboutIndex::class);
```

> app\Http\Livewire\HomeIndex

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Livewire;
    
    use Livewire\Attributes\Title;
    use Livewire\Component;
    
    class HomeIndex extends Component
    {
        #[Title('Home')]
    
        public $title = 'Dashboards';
    
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.home-index');
        }
    }
```

> views\livewire\home-index

```
    <div class="content-wrapper">
       Home Index page
    </div>
```

Similar livewire content for getAbout.

**Solution:**
Scripts in `<head>` are loaded once.
Scripts in the `<body>` are re-evaluated.
Because Livewire replaces the entire contents of the `<body>` on every new page, all `<script>` tags on the new page will be run:

```
<!-- Page one -->
<body>
    <script>
        console.log('Runs on page one')
    </script>
</body>
 
<!-- Page two -->
<body>
    <script>
        console.log('Runs on page two')
    </script>
</body>
```

If you have a `<script>` tag in the body that you only want to be run once, you can add the data-navigate-once attribute to the `<script>` tag and Livewire will only run it on the initial page visit:

```
<script data-navigate-once>
    console.log('Runs only on page one')
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps share some code so we can see how your files are constructed? There's not much to say from here other than ensure your JS and CSS files are not in a Livewire component.

Comment: okay, restructured the question.

Comment: I have used both the config as well as `view('livewire.home-index')->layout('layout');` and in both cases it works without reloading the JS and CSS. However, I also don't include the `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts` since that gets auto-injected with L3

Comment: that didnt work for me. using layout still reloads all css js

Comment: `<script data-navigate-once>
    console.log('Runs only on page one')
</script>` this works for me for the moment.